# Inner Join - SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have following tables:

```
Sales:
SalesID CustomerID  ZipCode
101     111         11331
102     222         NULL
103     333         11551
104     444         NULL


Customer:
CustomerID  Zipcode Customerphone
111         11331   4444444
222         11441   5555555
333         11551   7777777
444         11661   8888888

Contact:
CustomerID  CustomerName    CustomerEmail
111         John            john@email.com
222         Chris           chris@email.com
333         Mike            mike@email.com
444         Brian           brian@email.com
```

I want to join Sales table with Customer table on zipcode only when zipcode is not null in Sale table. If zipcode is null then map CustomerID in Sale table with CustomerID in Customer table. Then grap the CustomerID from Customer table and join with Contact table and finally get the CustomerName and CustomerEmail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT S.SalesID, CNT.CustomerName, CNT.CustomerEmail
FROM Sales S
LEFT JOIN Customer C1 ON C1.Zipcode = S.ZipCode
LEFT JOIN Customer C2 ON C2.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Contact CNT ON CNT.CustomerID = ISNULL(C1.CustomerID, C2.CustomerID)
```

If you know for sure you will get a customer, you can use an `INNER JOIN` with `Contact`.

Can a sale's `CustomerID` point to one user and the `ZipCode` to another? If it can't (there are no risk of duplicate joins), you can try this:

```
SELECT S.SalesID, CNT.CustomerName, CNT.CustomerEmail
FROM Sales S
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.Zipcode = S.ZipCode OR C.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Contact CNT ON CNT.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your reply. I want to mark your reply as answer but it is not letting me do that. May be I am doing something wrong. I am clicking the upper arrow but it is not updating. Please suggest me how to do that.

Comment: @johnmichael, no luck?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customer C
       JOIN Sales s
         ON c.zipcode = s.zipcode
             OR ( s.zipcode IS NULL
                  AND c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID )
       JOIN contact cc
         ON c.CustomerID = cc.CustomerID
```